# mootools doesn't work as a result of a "script5 access is denied error"

Tags: javascript, mootools, joomla2.5

I have three "content" slideshows on my joomla site (freeslider sp1) the javascript is powered by mootools. In all browsers they work fine except for IE. In IE9 I get the following error:

> SCRIPT5: Access is denied. 
>   mootools-core.js, line 483 character 2.

I have tried disabling jQuery, updating *`mootools-core.js`*.
I would like to fix this problem without rewriting *`mootools-core.js`* which is out of my capacity. The url is http://www.secureamericanow.org/

This issue has been driving me crazy!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in chrome's console:

> - XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.secureamericanow.org/index.php?obsstask=cronjob. Origin
>     http://www.secureamericanow.org is not allowed by
>     Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
> - XHR finished loading: "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y0/r/yy6VzIs1l_k.js".
>     like.php:242
> - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.secureamericanow.org/ from frame with URL
>     http://www.youtube.com/embed/VkYbkx1Cu64?rel=0&autoplay=1. Domains,
>     protocols and ports must match.

The page is violating the same origin policy.

The problem with the first error is one url is in https and the other is http. They have tpo both be http or https.

Comment: Thanks for the answer epascarello. Which of your points do you think is causing the moo-tools error in IE9?

Comment: access denied would be trying to access a different domain. Fix the cross domain issues.

Comment: it was the http calling the https that was the issue. Thanks buddy!